# UK visit visa declined

Tags: visas, uk

My partner has just had her UK visit visa declined under the grounds that she did not provide any assets or family that gives enough reason for her to return home.

I must admit I was fairly confident this visa would be approved as this is the third time we have applied, always providing the exact same documents and supporting evidence. Yet for some reason this time she has been refused.

Is there a way to appeal this or should I apply again? How can she prove her family ties? Bearing in mind on her application she states she has 3 dependent children not travelling with her, so she will clearly have to return home to look after them.

Comment: Why exactly was the visa refused?

Comment: Please post the refusal letter so that people can give you better answers. Blank out personal details.

Comment: The reason stated that my partner hadn’t listed any property assets or family ties that would encourage her return to the Philippines. Firstly my partner doesn’t own a property she rents the same house she was renting the last two times we applied for this visa. She has travelled to the UK 3 times already on 2 different 6 month visit visas, both applied for in exactly the same way that this one was. I will try to get a picture of the refusal letter later from my partner.

Comment: @J.Marsh: paraphrasing a small part of the refusal letter does not provide enough information for people to help. The best way to get a good answer is to scan the refusal letter, black-out any personal information and [edit the question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/106705/edit) to add the images of the refusal letter.

Comment: How frequent have the visits been and how long has she stayed each time? If the visits have been longer than a few weeks, how are dependent kids managing without her? (I know--other relatives but still).